# Grammarly says that starting "Like Pearl was hesitant to..." with "Like" is fine, but my parent says it is grammatically incorrect

Tags: word-choice, ellipsis, parallelism, run-on-sentences, as-like

Is following paragraph grammatically correct? My parent objected to me using "Like" in the beginning, but Grammarly was ok with it.

> *Like Pearl was hesitant to accept her father despite being expected to, have there been times when society has placed an expectation on
> you, and you have not immediately conformed to it? Why were you
> hesitant?*

Comment: By the way, it might be neater to construct the paragraph differently. "Despite it being expected of her, Pearl hesitated to accept her father. Have there been times..." etc.

Comment: I would suggest changing _like_ to _in the same way that_.

Comment: @KateBunting: Yes, or maybe "Just as..."

Comment: The usage of *like* is only one of many issues with this sentence.  The parenthetical comma is misused.  The words supporting *like* do not guide the reader toward your meaning.  Try starting the sentence with - *Like Pearl, who was hesitant to accept her father despite expectations, have there been times.....*

Comment: You are using "like" like slang. If you said: "Like a whisper in the night, the wind rose slowly", that would be fine. Also, sentence sounds neither like speaking nor writing,

Comment: It had me wondering if Pearl's first name was "Like". I would re-write. One way : Pearl was hesitant..., have there been similar times when ...?

Comment: This is fine as the start of a question

Comment: I understood instantly what you were asking, but it is not obvious to me how to explain the grammar of the sentence. Whether the sentence is technically grammatical or not, however, you have two things combined awkwardly in one sentence. I would delete "Like" and put a period after "to". In any case there should be no comma after "you" for the same reason that there should be no comma in the phrase "squares and triangles".

Comment: "Like, you know, whatever, grunt" is perhaps uttered by an inarticulate teenager. In reported speech it would illustrate the character. But perhaps there is a preceding sentence to which the 'like' refers, such as "Beryl always doubted her mother."

Comment: Like other commenters have mentioned, I find the sentence difficult to parse and would rearrange it.  I don't think you've used "like" incorrectly, though.

Comment: While "like" is [technically allowed](https://www.hotpepper.ca/blog/2015/09/28/using-like-to-introduce-clauses-another-myth-busted/), "just as" sounds better to my ear.  As others have said, though, this whole argument is a red herring.   The important thing is to rewrite the sentence to more eloquently express your idea, because the current structure is awkward.

Comment: It's grammatically correct in the dialect of English that I speak, but there may be other dialects in which it's not.  Where is your teacher from?

Comment: I'd definitely change `, and ` to simply `which`.  And definitely dump the final "it". Thus, "have there been times when society has placed an expectation on you which you have not immediately conformed to?"

Comment: This is a horribly formed sentence and is not something you would expect to find in common usage.  Don't be put-off.

Answer (score 23):

Grammarly is right because the sentence is grammatically correct. Your teacher has a point because there are several issues with the usage of **like** in this sentence.

According to the Cambridge Dictionary, the word [like](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/like), meaning "in the same way or manner as" can be a used either as a preposition or a conjunction. Here are examples of the two usages:

> The diamond sparkled on her finger like a snowflake in the sun. - *preposition*
> A woman needs a man like a fish needs a bicycle - *conjunction*

There are, however, constraints in the way that we use the conjunctional form: it does not sound natural if we use a different verb in the main and subordinate clauses, for example.

> She sings like her baby brother screams

The sentence is grammatically correct, but it sounds unnatural: in this case, this unnatural feeling can be used to emphasise the humorous nature of this comment.

Your sentence is a conjunctional usage of **like**, but the verb in the main clause is "have not immediately conformed" and the verb in the subordinate clause is "was hesitant". In addition, fronting the subordinate clause makes it feel more unnatural, harder to understand and more likely to get a knee-jerk "that's wrong" reaction.

You can eliminate these two problems by putting the main clause at the front and then using the same verb:

> Have you ever been hesitant when society has placed an expectation on you, like Pearl was [hesitant] when she was expected to accept her father?

There is one final consideration: while we use the prepositional form in spoken and written English, the conjunctional form is, for some reason, regarded as less acceptable in written English. Instead, we use **as** or **in the same way as**.

> Have you ever been hesitant when society has placed an expectation on you, as Pearl was [hesitant] when she was expected to accept her father?

With **as** there is no particular problem about using different verbs in the main and subordinate clauses:

> Have there been times when you **have not immediately conformed** when society has placed an expectation on you, as Pearl **was hesitant** when she was expected to accept her father?

Comment: @Jasper fair comment. I have rewritten my answer to provide direct **as** vs **like** comparisons.

Comment: Why do you say _"She sings like her baby brother screams"_ sounds unnatural? It sounds fine to me (native speaker here)

Comment: I thing that in the example "She sings like her baby brother screams", we are still comparing *ways/manners*: "She sings in a way that makes your ears bleed and her baby brother screams in a way that makes your ears bleed". But in the OP example, there is no *way or manner* in which Pearl was hesitant etc.  Rather, "Pearl was hesitant ..." is stated as a fact, and then a yes/no (not how!) question "have there been ..." is asked. Perhaps therefore the comparison between the two should perhaps be expressed differently, e.g., "Pearl was ... (period). Have there been *similar* situations ...?"

Comment: It's also possible to replace the *Like* in the original sentence with the possibly idiomatic *Just as.*

Comment: Like me, haven't you had enough? Grammatically correct? Yes. Like I was hesitant to accept this explanation, haven't you explained it in depth? Grammatically correct? No.

Comment: @Lambie your second sentence *is* grammatically correct, but it is semantic nonsense.  Here is a grammatically and semantically correct example from the Cambridge Dictionary: "Like I said, I don't wear perfume." https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/like

Comment: I was following: Like Pearl was hesitant to blah blah blah, haven't you etc. I really fail to see how that or my other example are grammatically "correct".

Comment: @Lambie  Rather than simply repeating "Its not grammatically correct", please explain what grammatical rule it breaks.

Comment: @JavaLatte Not everything that isn't an SVP breaks a rule. "like" can be used comparatively but not like this: Like I was hesitant to explain, haven't you ever explained anything too much?

Answer (score 22):

In the strictest sense, it is indeed grammatically correct. However, it’s not well written, and this is often misinterpreted as being equivalent to saying it’s grammatically incorrect. Consider for example the sentence ‘The old man the boat.’. A lot of people will claim this is ungrammatical, but it’s actually perfectly valid by the rules of English grammar (‘man’ in this case is a verb, not a noun, the subject is ‘the old’ (that is, elderly individuals), and the object is ‘the boat’). However, it’s difficult even for many native speakers to understand without re-reading it a couple of times (especially since ‘man’ used as a verb is less common these days than it used to be).

In your example, there is *syntactic ambiguity* inherent in the fronting of the subordinate clause: ‘Like Pearl was hesitant to accept her father despite being expected to’. In particular, ‘Like’ is ambiguous, it could be a filler word (similar to usage in phrases such as ‘Like really, dude.’), or it might be a conjunction that we’re missing the main clause for, it could in theory be a preposition, or it could even be part of a name (though this is not likely to be how most native speakers initially interpret it), and there’s no way to clearly determine this without reading most or all of the rest of the sentence, possibly multiple times (I had to read it twice to realize that it was a conjunction introducing a fronted subordinate clause). This ambiguity and the required resolution means that this is a [garden path sentence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garden-path_sentence#%22The_horse_raced_past_the_barn_fell.%22) like my example above, although it’s not exactly the best example of one (the ambiguity is relatively easy to resolve quickly and does not require any ‘special’ knowledge of the language).

Additionally, structure of the rest of the question is a bit complicated and sounds a little unnatural, though this is not exactly a crucial issue.

I see two ways to cleanly resolve the ambiguity and improve the structure of the rest of the question:

- Completely restructure the question to not front the subordinate clause. For example: ‘Have there been times when you did not immediately comply when society expected something of you, much like how Pearl was hesitant to accept her father?’. This resolves the ambiguity cleanly and also sounds a bit more natural, but still leaves you with a somewhat long sentence for the question, which is usually not considered a good thing stylistically.
- Completely restructure the paragraph, splitting the subordinate clause about Pearl to a separate sentence. For example: ‘Pearl was hesitant to accept her father, even though she was expected to. Have there been similar times when you did not immediately comply when society expected something of you?’. This also clearly resolves the ambiguity and sounds more natural, but keeps the example at the beginning (which I would consider preferable from a structural perspective) and avoids having an overly long question.

Comment: I wonder what Grammarly would say about "bulldogs bulldogs bulldogs fight fight fight"

Comment: +1 for grammatically correct but poorly written.

Comment: @Barmar Grammarly says that there are 2 "grammar, spelling, and punctuation" issues and 1 "consistency in spelling and punctuation" issue. However, the suggestions are for premium users, so I can't see the details.

Comment: If the OP's is grammatically correct, so is this, which uses the same exact structure: Like me was hesitant to accept [whatever], haven't you [...]? That is not grammatically correct. So the OP's sentence isn't either.

Comment: @Lambie That’s not grammatically correct because the specific pronoun used does not match how it’s used in the sentence. That sentence structure makes the first noun the subject of the first clause, which means that it needs to be ‘Like I was hesitant...’ instead. The entire rest of the sentence is perfectly grammatical though.

Comment: Sorry, I meant  what you just wrote: Like I was hesitant to accept x, haven't you done blah blah blah? That is not grammatical. It just isn't. It's a run-on sentence basically.. Just as I was hesitant to accept x, haven't you done blah blah blah.

Comment: @Lambie It’s actually not a run-on sentence at all. The subordinate clause is rather clearly dependent on the main clause (it cannot be a a sentence on it’s own, or a main clause for a different sentence, without rewriting). It is arguably a bit long, and the fronting of the subordinate clause leads to syntactic ambiguity as pointed out in the answer, but those are _stylistic_ issue, and writing style  is not part of grammar, even if many schools treat it as such.

Comment: I constructed a sentence just like the OP's above. You are not responding so here it is again: *Like I was hesitant to accept the idea, haven't you ever blah blah blah?*. Same thing, right? That just does not pass the smell test for me even if in speech we might say it. I find it to be ungrammatical.

Comment: @Lambie And I reiterate, it’s not ungrammatical, it’s poorly written, and the two are different things that are often confused. There are no issues with the syntax, morphology, or phonology, ergo it is not a problem of grammar. There is initial ambiguity in the fronting of the subordinate clause which requires reading the whole sentence to resolve, but that is a style issue, not a grammar issue. I’m not saying that it’s a _good_ sentence (in fact, I argue it is not, but for stylistic reasons), just that there are no grammar issues with it.

Answer (score 5):

Your paragraph is grammatically correct.

Your teacher was wise to ask you to re-write it.

As written, the paragraph is difficult to understand.  The first question is very long.  I needed to read it twice before I could correctly parse it.  I needed to read it a third time before I understood what it meant.

By the way, my previous paragraph's use of "As" is similar to your use of "Like".  Both introduce an example.  Both are terse, formal ways of saying "like in the text the way it is" or "like in the situation where".

Comment: Only twice? I think it took me 3 or 4 times.

Comment: This kind of sentence is called a “crash blossom.” I also didn’t understand how *like* was being used until I got to the end, and then I had to go back and re-read from the beginning. It's very jarring to a native speaker in a way it might not be to a student when we have to stop and consciously analyze a sentence, breaking our flow.

Comment: It is most definitely not grammatically correct.

Answer (score 5):

It's not quite correct. It's missing one word, at a minimum: "Like *when* Pearl..." or "Like the time when Pearl..."

Alternatively, you could recast the sentence and make it slightly more formal:

"Like Pearl when she..."

Also: "As when Pearl..."

Comment: You have made it "slightly more formal" by changing the conjunctional usage to **like** to a prepositional usage with Pearl as the prepositional object: see my answer for why this works.

Comment: I would have used "how". While the other answers are convincing in saying that the original construction is _technically_ correct, it feels wrong enough that I don't understand the original sentence, so I think you're right.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 Agreed -- "how" is fine too.

Comment: Sorry but this: [It was or it was as if ] Like Pearl was hesitant to accept her father despite being expected to, **have there been times** when society has placed an expectation on you. It's a completely run-on sentence with that "have there been times" which is trying to be a question.

Comment: I think the "when" corrects the fundamental flaw in the original sentence, which is that it uses the word "like" to compare an emotional state  in "Pearl was hesitant," to a time in "have there been times when".  You could also say "Like Pearl was hesitant..., have you ever declined to conform when..."

Comment: Amazing, I gave all sorts of details and get 4 downvotes; you get only upvotes. I think people are writers around here.

Comment: @Lambie Actually, I have 6 upvotes and 2 downvotes. I didn't see your answer till you pinged me just now and have upvoted it. I think it says much the same thing, but I find the "young people" paragraph a misdirection, since I don't think either of us considers this to be that use of "like", right?

Comment: Yes, I think it's not great. Take a look at my comments under Javalatte. Like Pearl when she, Like Pearl who was, Just like Pearl who was, etc. As when Pearl. :) Many ways to say it *except* the way it's in the question.

Answer (score -2):

Sample sentence:
*Like* Pearl was hesitant to accept her father despite being expected to, have there been times when society has placed an expectation on you, and you have not immediately conformed to it? Why were you hesitant?

Young people use *like* all the time when speaking: "Like, I really didn't want to go". That is used in spoken discourse, not in writing, but even if used in writing it would have to be set off by commas. However, just like is used to point to a particular situation.

I suspect you mean this:
**Just like** Pearl was hesitant to accept her father['s wishes] despite being expected to, **haven't there been times when society has placed expectations on you**, and you have not immediately conformed to it? Why were you hesitant?

Now it balances the sentences since "just like" is explained in relation to the person being addressed by the author's question.

**Just like** your sisters, **haven't you always** [or even] dyed your hair?

**Like your** sisters, **haven't you always [or ever] dyed your hair**?

OR

**Like** Pearl **who** was hesitant to accept her father['s wishes] despite being expected to, **haven't there been times when society has placed expectations on you**, and you have not immediately conformed to it? Why were you hesitant?

like is used to compare one person or thing to another. And "just like" can make it much clearer. The reader is being addressed by the author who is comparing the character's situation to your own or her own situation.

Comment: The "just" here is optional and synonymous, though does reduce ambiguity, and ease parsing of the sentence. While the meaning is unchanged without it, this answer seems to imply that 'Just' is grammatically required. The bolding didn't clarify anything, at least for me, and I'm unsure what it's meant to indicate: both of the "your sisters" sentences seem to parse without issue for me.

Comment: @DewiMorgan Of course, it is optional. But it makes the thing clearer as the comparison is much further down in your sentence. I gave two examples of my own and the same sentence, one with just and one without. Those examples of mine have the **same structure** as yours.